# Grunt imagemin - 'optimizationLevel' not working

Tags: html, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

Everything is fine except one case is that `optimizationLevel` is not working.

I dont get result based on **optimizationLevel**  level change (level from 1 to 7)

```
imagemin:{
        dynamic:{
            options:{
                optimizationLevel: 1
            },
            files:[{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'work/imgs/',
                src: ['*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'work/imgs'
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try changing dest?

Comment: Yes , nothing different result